# Alternative of SQL as client side Storage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

i am making a client side project on Winform 4.0 or WPF, the problem is how can i store my data at client side having no SQL server installation. I will provide a setup of my application which will be run by my client. Client cant install SQL server. Is there database avaiable in .net that doesn't required sql installation or any other way?

Comment: SQLite is a recommended for client side data storage.

Comment: Also, Microsoft SQL Compact Edition is free

Comment: [linqdb](https://github.com/ren85/linqdb)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), which requires no installation. There are some ORMs out there that support SQLite, for example [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) (which is used by StackOverflow as well.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do with just simple data you can use SQL Server CE or SQLite. Both will store data as files that you can create and access from code. To do this you'll just need some dlls in your project, no installation. But be sure to analyse the limitations - some data types are not supported by these simple data bases etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [RavenDb](http://ravendb.net/)

You can have it embedded in your app. Fast and elegant

Answer (score 2):

Something not mentionned yet: [ManagedEsent](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/). Simple to use and fast. For simple persitence, there is a [PersistentDictionary](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation&referringTitle=Home) class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292880/create-sqlite-database-and-table/15292958#15292958) database, for this.

If you only want to store small things, like settings, I would recommend you the following link [Build-in Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx), this is easier in use, than selecting, updating, inserting and deleting from a SQLite database. Another Pro is, that no dlls are required.

Answer (score 0):

[EntityWorker.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityWorker.Core/) new ORM and similar to entityframwork