# C# - How to copy SQLite db from one path and paste it to another path?

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection-string

Using below code, how can I set the code in SQLiteConnetion object ?

`public SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection();`

```
string fileName = "test.s3db";
        string sourcePath = @"E:\File\DMS\DAL\Model";
        string targetPath = @"C:\ProgramData\CompanyName\appName";
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        }
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
        }
```

I want to automatically create a DB path if the path does not exist.

```
dbConnection = ??
```

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by _"how can I set the code in SQLiteConnetion object"_? Your code seems to be correct. Could you provide a code snippet on what is not working?

Comment: @botond.botos hi Actually I am facing the problem is, please look this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689467/where-to-store-my-windows-applications-data . Then I thought create a default path when install my application on any local computer while creating setup file in wpf c#

Comment: There's a different approach described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292880/create-sqlite-database-and-table. Instead of copying a database file it creates it on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this method to copy database:

```
public static void BackupDatabase(string sourceFile, string destFile)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection source = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source = {0}", sourceFile)))
    using (SQLiteConnection destination = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source = {0}", destFile)))
    {
        source.Open();
        destination.Open();
        source.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. This is my Database--   string fileName = "test.s3db";

Comment: @AbhilashJA So you should replace `YourDatabase.db` with `test.s3db`.

Comment: How can I locate these two path ? string sourcePath = @"E:\File\DMS\DAL\Model";
          string targetPath = @"C:\ProgramData\CompanyName\appName"; 
By using this code?

Comment: What are the benefits of using `SQLiteConnection.BackupDatabase(...)` over simple file copy?

Comment: @botond.botos Maybe that you don't have to write file copy code?

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski, I was asking because copying a file doesn't take more lines of code than creating a backup with `SQLiteConnection` API.

Comment: @botond.botos Maybe backup file has some additional information and somehow differs from a simple copy?

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski, that's what I was hoping you can explain when I asked about the added benefits.

Comment: @botond.botos Unfortunately, I can't.

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski How can I assign this static void to sqliteconnection object?  dbConnection = BackupDatabase();

Comment: @AbhilashJA This method just makes a copy of a database. You can create new `dbConnection` right after this method: `BackupDatabase(); dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source = {0}", destFile));`