# need to deploy winforms application on client pc without install sql management on client pc

Tags: c#, winforms

i have winforms application C# connected with sql server database and working fine on my pc sure because of link for database but when try to deploy it on anther pc it get errors for database
the application didn't install with database so how to solve this issue ?
the application data is small is there anyway to use scripts from sql to another small database on client pc to make application work ?

Comment: Is the database local? If yes, just get yourself with SQL Express and make sure the connection string is correct, you need not SSMS. SSMS is just for navigating through the database.

Comment: Another option is [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15), it is a version of sql server that runs like an application, so less installation needed

Comment: Install SSMS which is just the interfaces and not the SQL Server (or Express).

Comment: What is the error please provide detailed error information? Can you provide more information what your code looks like. Do you use ODBC connections or SqlServerConnection (named pipes, IP) etc.? what did you try already?

Comment: [How to deploy application with SQL Server database on client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956142/how-to-deploy-application-with-sql-server-database-on-clients/32956485#32956485)

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292880/create-sqlite-database-and-table).

Comment: i use sql server local db (sql mangement studio) and using tables and procedures