# How do I corrupt a SQL CE Database?

Tags: sql-server-ce, corruption

I want to be able to check for a corrupted database at startup, and then repair it programmatically.  I can [do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172420.aspx) easily enough.

My problem is that I want to test that things work the way I expect.  Does anyone know of a way to purposefully corrupt a database so I can test my code?

Comment: Open it as a bit-stream and change a few random bits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the SDF file into a byte array, randomly alter some of the bytes and save the array back over the original file (or for that matter, load the file into a hex editor and go all Shakespeare's monkeys on it).

I think this will do what you want without doing what you want.  In my experience, the problems that I've had with corrupted SqlCE databases weren't fixed by `SqlCeEngine.Repair` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291346/sync-nightmare-is-it-possible-to-use-merge-replication-or-rda-between-2-sql-c/1291367#1291367) to a related question).  It may be that `Repair` can fix a database that has had some of its bytes randomly altered, but I'm sure this would depend on where in the file the alteration occured (e.g. in a data page somewhere or in the file header, if there is one).